# Deny connection to and from a specific hostname on Ubuntu/Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, .htaccess

My wordpress EC2 server was probably hacked. When running `iftop` command I can see  that my server sends and recieves data from a hostname name "i157panamamails.com".

This hostname never goes away and eating lots of bandwidth. I want to prevent the server from communicating with this hostname and deny it completely. I tried putting a `deny from` in the .htaccess and restart the Apache2 server (using Ubuntu 10.0), but it didn't help, I an still see that hostname connection active. Maybe the connection is not from Apache2, but from what I know this is the only server installed.

How can I prevent the server to deny this hostname?

More info:

- in `etc/hosts` I have only 127.0.0.1
- in etc/resolve.conf I have:

  nameserver [some_ip_address] <--- this IP is for EC2, so not problem here

  domain ec2.internal

  search ec2.internal
- The IP in the resolve.conf doesn't resolve to host name
- Using lsof command on port 22/21/80 Can't find the host name in the connections. Port 21 has one connection for root user listening, but port 21 is not open in EC2 security groups and port 443 (HTTPS) has no connections
- It seems that the connection is not on port 80 of apache because lsof shows only my connection at a specific time frame and I see the connection for that hostname still active in the network print. I assume that another software that acts as a server might initialize that connection on an already open port 80 that is not related to Apache
- Running NetHogs on eth0 shows me that a program **sshd: ubuntu@pts1** under user `ubuntu` which is continuously receiving and sending data (not Apache2). Looks suspicious
- I also notice a lot of connection (~50) from a PROGRAM 37:80-[ip_addresses] on port 80 and other ports. Those PROGRAM(s) do not send or receive data (most of them)
- Blocking the hostname in the host.deny didn't help

**Update:**
I've find out the IP and blocked it in IPtables (both OUTPUT and INPUT). The IP server doesn't send data to that IP, **but** it dos receives a 240 bytes every second or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first of all you can run tcpdump on your server to analyze traffic.

```
tcpdump -s 65535 -w ~/traffic_capture.pcap
```

Then you can read from this file with command:

```
tcpdump -vv -r ~/traffic_capture.pcap
```

or download it your computer and check it with wireshark.

Also you can use iptables to log all of your outgoing traffic(here is rule):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG
```

By default log of this traffic will be in /var/log/kern.log.

Also you can run iftop with flag -n which will prevent iftop from doing hostname lookups.

Quote from manpages of iftop:

```
   By  default, iftop will look up the hostnames associated with addresses
   it finds in packets. This can cause substantial traffic of itself,  and
   may  result in a confusing display. You may wish to suppress display of
   DNS traffic by using filter code such as not port domain, or switch  it
   off  entirely, by using the -n option or by pressing r when the program
   is running.
```

If you are sure that you got some kind of shell or malware, then you can try use maldet or ai-bolit to check for malware in apache's directories.

Comment: You thirds option allowed me to see the IP address! .. checking if I can block it.

Comment: The ip resolves to Netherlands, the same country that ddos my xmlrp.php which I blocked in htaccess earlier. We are in the right direction

Comment: Great that could help you. You can block this ip address on iptables completely.

Comment: @Navem How can I enable the ip again if I want it to work again, just in case?

Comment: You can check which line blockig rule is with iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers and then run iptables -D <CHAIN> <LINE-NUMBER> to delete rule from specific chain on specific line.

Comment: @Navem, I can still see the IP, but no data is being transfered which is  excellent. I want to know how to be able to not see that IP in the list, and if so, what does it means when it is blocked and can still see it?

Comment: I think you can see it because it's incoming traffic and you blocked outgoing traffic. Try to block this IP in INPUT chain also and check for iftop output again.

Comment: @Navem I used OUTPUT but I can still see that IP (without traffic)

Comment: Update, the IP DOES have a few incoming bytes (240 bytes)

Comment: Yes, you should block it in input also. Then you won't see this traffic. Right now it happens this way.

Packet coming to interface, reply can't go from this interface because of blocking rule.

Comment: I blocked them both. but I still see it. Maybe the bytes are there because of the call to the server, and that's the reason why I see it, is it?

Comment: Yep, i think it's true. Check it with tcpdump. 

tcpdump -i any -vv 'host <BLOCKED_IP>'

Comment: I see PuTTY commands with gibrish, is it the attacker commands?

Comment: Can I know if it attacked my domain or IP address. If it's my IP address I can change it?

Comment: Actually you can't know. I think you should scan your host for malware and hardening your defense. 

If you have actual piece of malware i believe you can create separate topic.

Comment: Any recommendation of a good malware scanner?

Comment: maldet and ai-bolit - it is what i know and use when scan for shells. Actually it isn't detecting everything and have false positives sometimes. But good start point.

Answer (score 2):

You should try iptables for a quick fix.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 202.54.1.22 -j DROP
```

@see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-6-how-to-block-outgoing-access-to-selectedspecific-ip-address.html

On EC2, if you're running in a VPC, you can edit your ACL on-the-fly and block this IP.

However, if you were indeed hacked, this is just the first step. Take a look at the process that's doing those connections, lsof will help, figure out why it's running and who installed it and remove it from your machine if needed.

The second step would be to harden your security:
 - upgrade wordpress to the latest version; there are some popular exploits for this platform
 - change all IAM and master account passwords
 - rotate all aws access keys and ssh keys
 - make sure you cannot ssh using passwords
 - if possible, allow ssh only from specific IPs, via Security Groups

Comment: Hi, the problem that I can't reverse the hostname to an IP. This is urgent, please guide..

Comment: Hmm, yes I saw that. I cannot ping it either. Take a look in /etc/hosts and see if you have some rules only for this server.

Comment: Also, /etc/resolv.conf maybe someone changed your DNS settings. You should see IPs of DNS servers in there.

Comment: I update the question with info. In resolv.conf I see a nameserver with IP address (See the question body). Any idea if the IP should be there?

Comment: The IP should be there, it should point to a aws nameserver, usually from the class 10.x.x.x or 172.x.x.x

Comment: VladFr, yes, it start with 172, so this part is fine. Trying to use lsof  now

Comment: I've updated the question with more info. Is there a way to know which script/file/process is connecting to that specific hostname?

Answer (score 0):

It might be outbound connection rather than inbound. Check below activity:

1. Top command. You might want to stop other services so that it is
   more obvious which process is using CPU.
2. Ping i157panamamails.com and see whether it can resolve to an IP on
   your server. If it does,
       block it on iptables.
3. Block all outbound connections on your AWS security group if you
   don't need outbound connections.

Apart from those reactive measures, I would also recommend you to install host based intrusion detection software such as OSSEC to detect unauthorized access and changes to your system.

Comment: using top, I see that apache2 and mysqld are the main ones that are consistently have active CPU. I assume that if someone hacked the server, the server might not have a process footpring (or am I wrong)?